# Top network posts can be misleading

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, top-network-posts

In my profile, can see the following "Top Network Posts"

[image]

This doesn't show

- Q&As from current community
- Answers in questions that got closed

Could we also show it or add an info icon with a modal explaining it doesn't show that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not unclear or misleading. Those things are omitted for a good reason, IMO.

- > Q&As from current community

  Those are not shown because the goal of the widget is to draw attention to the other sites in Stack Exchange network. Visitor of the profile see those, and might check the other sites as result.
- > Answers in questions that got closed

  Closed question means it's not a good fit for the site. It should not have been answered in the first place, so such answer can't be "top".

---

I do agree that it can be good idea to add something like this:

[image: Help icon in top network posts]

When hovering over it, a tooltip with explanation will appear, or link to some help page explaining more about it, including the reasons above.

Comment: Shadow 10 Years Wizard the name "Top network posts" then is not correct because it's not really _network_. When it comes to the closed question, its answers can be given before it was closed. I'm speaking in particular of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63845592/5675325) which whose question was closed based on an [expert decision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401155/5675325)... yet, people seem to be liking a lot that Q&A which was asked 2 months ago

Comment: In the [Network profile top section](https://stackexchange.com/users/7465632/tiago-martins-peres-%e6%9d%8e%e5%a4%a7%e4%bb%81?tab=top) the answer to the closed question shows up though

Comment: @Tiago well it does show posts from all other sites in the network, with the highest score. How else you want to call it? I added a suggestion to my answer, this can be turned to actual feature request if you want. (By posting a new feature request.)

Comment: Something like "Top in other communities" but that icon was what I was envisioning too. Changing the text would be ok too but even then it wouldn't cover the case of the answers to closed questions not showing up (which is something showing in top of the network profile) (so the icon would be the easiest)

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 "Top in other communities" It will sometimes (depending on the community and the current list of HNQ posts) show posts of the same (not other) community *as well*. I don't think the current community is taken into account when showing HNQ.

Comment: @Mast i checked in SO, Meta, PM and Sci-fi and they were excluded (hence the assumption it follows through with that behavior)

Comment: "Other Communities Top Posts" can also be used. The word "Other" seems relevant as one is excluding the one that one is in.